# webrtc with python show realtime Temperature on a Web page

Tags: python, websocket, raspberry-pi, webrtc

my project based on a comparison between Websocket and Webrtc .until now its works very well using Websocket , It is a python script that runs a Websocket server  to send the realtime data temperature  to the client.What its next to do  is the same thing using Webrtc :I know that
The Webrtc is based on a triangular and peer-to-peer architecture in which a central server is used to connect two peers wishing to exchange  data streams(temperature)but I'm a beginner and i don't know what schould i change in my coding way.
i was checking out the project"webRTC without browser", but it doesn't describe what I'm looking for. . Is there a way to do it with the current setup or some examples like this project? i will be greatfull if i find someone cann help me to do it rignt .

servertemperature.py

```
import time
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
import tornado.web

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self,origin):
        return True
    def open(self):
        self.callback = PeriodicCallback(self.send_temp, 120)
        self.callback.start()

    def send_hello(self):
        self.write_message('hello')

    def on_message(self, message):
        pass

    def on_close(self):
        self.callback.stop()
        print "Closed Connection"

    def send_temp(self):


        #Change this to the file of your temp probe!

        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-03139779f433/w1_slave")
        text = tfile.read()
        tfile.close()
        temperaturedata = text.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
        temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
        temperature = temperature / 1000 * 9 / 5 + 32
        self.write_message("Current Temperature: {0:.2f}F".format(temperature))
        print temperature
        time.sleep(1)


application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', WSHandler),])

if _name_ == "_main_":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8080)
    print 'Server begin'
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>BlenderWebController</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script>
                //Change this to the locla ip of your pi
                var address = "ws://10.61.150.226:8080/"
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    try {
                            var s = new WebSocket(address);
                            s.onopen = function (e) {
                                $("#Status").slideUp();
                            };
                            s.onclose = function (e) {
                                $("#Status > div > p").text("Not Connected");
                                $("#Status").slideDown();
                            };
                            s.onmessage = function (e) {
                                $("#templog > li").removeClass("hightlight");
                                $("#templog").prepend('<li class="list-group-item hightlight"></li>');
                                $("#templog > li").first()
                                .hide()
                                .text( e.data + ' @ ' + (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString() )
                                .slideDown("slow");
                            };
                            s.onerror = function (e) {
                                $("#Status > div > p").text("Something Died!");
                                $("#Status").slideDown();
                            };
                    } catch (ex) {
                        $("#Status > div > p").text("Something Died!");
                        $("#Status").slideDown();
                    }
                    $("#close").click( function () {
                        s.close(1000, "Try to Close");
                    });
            });

        </script>
        <style>
            .hightlight{
                font-size: 2em;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: rgb(138, 109, 59);
                background-color: rgb(252, 248, 227);
                border-color: rgb(250, 235, 204); 
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="Status">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <strong>Warning</strong><p></p>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading" >
                        <h2 class="panel-title" style="display:inline;font-size:160%;" >Temperature Log</h2>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="close" style="display:inline;float:right;">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul id="templog" class="list-group">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to create a minimal reproducible example